# Detecting whether a user clicked on correct designated area of an image in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, user-interface, canvas

I am working on a quiz tool where one of the questions is of image type.

Imagine you are creating the test for your students and you upload an image of a car. You then mark two doors of the car and your question is - `Click on one of the doors of the car below`.
The student, when on this question, will see the same image without any markings/annotations. 
If the student clicks on the door he/she gets the point, not otherwise. Note: The car doors are random shapes and can be a polygon and preferably can be drawn using a brush tool, sort of.

Here are some thoughts I have but is there a better way or a library that suits this?:

The UI is built in React, the data format can be anything as long as it works.

1. A library that could draw and capture Polygons on an image like [this](https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw) or [this](https://github.com/waoai/react-image-annotate). 
   I can then run a "point lies inside polygon" algorithm like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/). But that also sounds like overkill. (And I am not sure if they distinguish between multiple polygons cleanly).
2. A library that does both the tasks of option 1.
3. Anything else better?

Sorry if this is asked before, but my question is more React focused and I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [react-image-annotate](https://github.com/waoai/react-image-annotate). 
The library not only allows you to draw on an image but also presents components with a nice UI. The bar on the left allows users to choose between drawing points, polygons and binding boxes. There are also tools to pan, drag, and zoom. The panels on the right keep track of drawn regions and history. There is also a fullscreen mode and also supports annotating videos!

[image]
The full UI can be rendered using `Annotator` or `ReactImageAnnotate` component:

```
import Annotator from "react-image-annotate"
    const App = () => (
      <Annotator
        selectedImage="https://example.com/image1.png"
        enabledTools={["create-point", "create-polygon"]}
        images={[{ src: "https://example.com/image1.png", name: "Image 1" }]}
        regionClsList={["Man Face", "Woman Face"]}
        onExit={(props)=> {console.log(props)}}
      />
    )
```

You can also display previously drawn regions/annotations without any tools with `ImageCanvas`:

```
import ImageCanvas from "react-image-annotate/ImageCanvas"
<ImageCanvas imageSrc="https://example.com/image1.png" regions: regions/>
```

`onExit` method is called when clicking on Save button from the UI, where you can get all the annotations on an image.